# Python function missing positional arguments

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am using Tkinter in python. I have created a canvas and I am trying to move a widget from its position.
But now I am getting this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Udasi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Udasi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 749, in callit
    func(*args)
TypeError: move_up() missing 6 required positional arguments: 'tag', 'parent', 'root', 'pady_top', 'x', and 'y'
```

Here's the code:

```
import tkinter

def move_up(tag, parent, root, pady_top, x, y):
    y-=10
    parent.move(tag, 0, -10)
    if(y>pady_top):
        root.after(100, move_up)
    else:
        parent.move(tag, 0, y-pady_top)
    return y


def float_top(tag, widget, parent, root, pady_top, x, y):
    move_up(tag, parent, root, pady_top, x, y)
```

I don't understand where the issue is.
Here's the code in a separate file that's calling it:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import animations

class App():
    def __init__(self, colors, logo_loc):
        self.colors = colors
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.state("zoomed")
        self.rootFrame = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=self.root.winfo_width(), height=self.root.winfo_height())
        self.rootFrame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.logo_loc=logo_loc

    def firstScreen(self):
        self.rootFrame.config(background=self.colors['primary'])
        x = (self.root.winfo_width()//2)    
        y = (self.root.winfo_height()//2)
        self.logo_tag="logo"
        self.logo_id=self.rootFrame.create_image(x+10, y, image=self.logo, tags="logo")
        animations.float_top(self.logo_tag, self.logo, self.rootFrame, self.root, 100, x, y)

    def loadLogo(self):
        self.logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=self.logo_loc)
        self.root.update()


class Controller:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        self.app.loadLogo()
        self.app.firstScreen()


colors = {'primary':"#1e1e1e", 'secondary':"#001ec8", 'tertiary':"#e6a00a", 'common':"#f0f0f0"}


app = App(colors, "assets/musik.PNG")
controller = Controller(app)
app.root.mainloop()
```

Specifically it's here:

```
animations.float_top(self.logo_tag, self.logo, self.rootFrame, self.root, 100, x, y)
```

I also tried passing 5 arguments, then it raised the same error saying 1 positional argument missing... but when I pass them all, it says all arguments missing!

Comment: How are you calling `move_up()`? Because the error is not in the implementation of the `move_up` function but how you called it.

Comment: I called it in float_top() function. Earlier I was using lambda but now I removed the lambda function and directly calling it gives the same error.

Comment: That call stack shows that `float_top` isn't actually involved.

Comment: Where do you pass it to `tkinter` as a callback (probably with `command=move_up` in some argument list)? Because the exception says that some library code is trying to call it, but failing.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details. Please check now.

Comment: You did not pass the arguments in `root.after(100, move_up)` inside `move_up()`.  Should be `root.after(100, move_up, tag, parent, root, pady_top, x, y)`.

Comment: @acw1668 You are a genius bro!!! Thank you... got my problem.solved()

Answer (score 0):

I copied you code and run on macOS with python 3.7. There are no error promoted but also, no window is displayed. According to the error info, the exception is report in `tkinter`. Specificly, the error is reported in class `CallWrapper`, the code of which is

```py
class CallWrapper:
    # ...
    def __call__(self, *args):
        """Apply first function SUBST to arguments, than FUNC."""
        try:
            if self.subst:
                args = self.subst(*args)
            return self.func(*args)
        except SystemExit:
            raise
        except:
            self.widget._report_exception()
```

Notice that only `SystemExit` is raised. Other exceptions, like `TypeError` are processed internally and only part of the error info is printed. To check the full error stack, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388271/how-to-handle-errors-in-tkinter-mainloop) you can override `CallWrapper` using:

```py
class TkErrorCatcher:

    '''
    In some cases tkinter will only print the traceback.
    Enables the program to catch tkinter errors normally

    To use
    import tkinter
    tkinter.CallWrapper = TkErrorCatcher
    '''

    def __init__(self, func, subst, widget):
        self.func = func
        self.subst = subst
        self.widget = widget

    def __call__(self, *args):
        try:
            if self.subst:
                args = self.subst(*args)
            return self.func(*args)
        except SystemExit as msg:
            raise SystemExit(msg)
        except Exception as err:
            raise err

import tkinter
tkinter.CallWrapper = TkErrorCatcher
```

which will raise all errors. Try the code above and review the full error stack.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is where I call move_up in root.after(100, move_up)... I need to pass arguments in there!

```
root.after(100, move_up)
```

Instead it should be

```
root.after(100, move_up, tag, parent, root, pady_top, x, y)
```