# Understanding exception handling during tkinter mainloop

Tags: python, tkinter, exception

Trying to figure out how to catch errors thrown during the `mainloop` in my code. Why in the MRE below is the `AttributeError` exception not caught by my `try`/`except` block? How can I handle the exception?

If I put a `print` statement under `root.mainloop()`, it doesn't print before the exception is thrown by clicking the button in the program, so I feel like the program isn't progressing out of the `try` section until the exception is thrown. So why is it not caught?

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button

class Example:
    def __init__(self, root):
        Button(root, text="Throw Error", command=self.throwError).pack(padx=30, pady=30)
    
    def throwError(self, **args):
        raise AttributeError("Example Error")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        root = Tk()
        Example(root)
        root.mainloop() # program seems to stay here til exception raised
    except AttributeError as e:
        print("Error caught") # never gets run
```

---

Per the answer below, here's the code that let me handle the errors by inserting it to the second line of the program above (see linked post):

```py
import tkinter
class TkExceptionHandler:
    def __init__(self, func, subst, widget):
        self.func = func
        self.subst = subst
        self.widget = widget

    def __call__(self, *args):
        if self.subst:
            args = self.subst(*args)
        return self.func(*args)

tkinter.CallWrapper = TkExceptionHandler
```

Comment: What is the attribute error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because there is another `try / except` block inside tkinter code which handled the exception.

When the code is executed, the following exception traceback is shown in the console:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\temp\python\demo93.py", line 8, in throwError
    raise AttributeError("Example Error")
AttributeError: Example Error
```

So if you look into tkinter source file at line 1892:

```
    def __call__(self, *args):
        """Apply first function SUBST to arguments, than FUNC."""
        try:
            if self.subst:
                args = self.subst(*args)
            return self.func(*args)     ### <-- this is line 1892
        except SystemExit:
            raise
        except:
            self.widget._report_exception()
```

So the `AttributeError` is handled by the `try / exception` block.  As you notice in the tkinter code, `SystemExit` is re-raised.  So your code can raise `SystemExit` instead of `AttributeError`:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button

class Example:
    def __init__(self, root):
        Button(root, text="Throw Error", command=self.throwError).pack(padx=30, pady=30)

    def throwError(self, **args):
        raise SystemExit("Example Error")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        root = Tk()
        Example(root)
        root.mainloop() # program seems to stay here til exception raised
    except SystemExit as e:
        print("Error caught:", e)
```

Then you will get the following in console and the program exits:

```
Error caught: Example Error
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped me make sense of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35390914/13597979) so I could write a new CallWrapper class that better fitted my needs. Just flagged the post as a duplicate.